# XSL Get all processing instructions between current element and previous element

Tags: xml, xslt

Given the following sample xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <data>
        <?format-number id?>
        <id>123</id>
        <?xml-multiple comment?>
        <?format-string comment?>
        <comment>hello</comment>
        <?format-string comment?>
        <comment>goodbye</comment>
        <text>bar</text>
    </data>
</root>
```

I need to write an XSL that copies a given element, as well as *all* preceding processing instructions *until* the previous element (either sibling or parent).  The copy of processing instructions should be generic (it doesn't matter what the instructions are, as long as they logically "belong" to the element (i.e. think of them as annotations on the subsequent element, and there may be multiple of them).  It also doesn't matter what the previous element is (again, it could be the same element name, a different element name, or a parent element).

An XSL might look something like:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="2.0">
  <xsl:output byte-order-mark="no" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" method="xml"
    omit-xml-declaration="yes" />


  <xsl:template match="/">
    <root>
      <xsl:for-each select="/root/data">
        <data>
          <xsl:for-each select="comment">
            <!-- some select usage of preceding-sibling and processing-instruction() ? -->
            <xsl:copy-of select="???" />
            <xsl:copy-of select="." />
            <foo>bar</foo>
          </xsl:for-each>
          <xsl:for-each select="text">
            <xsl:copy-of select="." />
          </xsl:for-each>
        </data>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </root>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Based on the above, the result should be:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <data>
        <?xml-multiple comment?>
        <?format-string comment?>
        <comment>hello</comment>
        <?format-string comment?>
        <comment>goodbye</comment>
        <text>bar</text>
    </data>
</root>
```

**Update**

Additional context.  I have some existing xsl that was written/tested in a way that targets specific elements as it transforms (i.e. heavy use of `for-each select="element"`).  That xsl was generated from MapForce (a graphical mapping tool), but doesn't copy over xml processing instructions!.  Ideally I could augment this existing xsl in a way that is relatively unobtrusive (i.e. adding some xsl right before each `copy-of` inside the `for-each` that copies that particular elements processing instructions.

Basically, the trick is to include a snippet that says "inside a `for-each` that selects an element, first copy all over the current element's processing instructions (those that come before the current element, but after the previous element), then do whatever logic was already in there, i.e. more `copy-of`, etc.

**Update 2**

After further testing of the `key` based answer below, another edge-case popped up in which there are at times "orphaned" processing instructions, i.e. those which don't annotate a `following-sibling` element, but come at the end, i.e. `<?xml-multiple colors?>` below.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <data>
        <?format-number id?>
        <id>123</id>
        <?xml-multiple comment?>
        <?format-string comment?>
        <comment>hello</comment>
        <?format-string comment?>
        <comment>goodbye</comment>
        <?format-string text?>
        <text>bar</text>
        <?xml-multiple colors?>
    </data>
</root>
```

In this case, the result *should* be

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <data>
        <?xml-multiple comment?>
        <?format-string comment?>
        <comment>hello</comment>
        <?format-string comment?>
        <comment>goodbye</comment>
        <text>bar</text>
        <?xml-multiple colors?>
    </data>
</root>
```

This is tricky because it doesn't have a `following-sibling`, rather, it has no "target" element.  Along these lines, I also realized that the processing instructions "data" (i.e. if `format-number` is the name, `id` is the data) is really the thing that ties it to a target.   In this respect, what I really want is to do a copy-of processing-instructions based on the element they target.  In other words, I think I want to create the key based on the node referenced in the processing instruction vs the following-sibling.

```xml
<xsl:copy-of select="key('pi', generate-id('foo'))" />
```

would stamp out processing-instructions that were indexed because they were found as:

```xml
<?format-number foo?>
<id>123</id>
```

Comment: If you are using XSLT 2.0, please attach that tag to your question; it's much easier to answer this kind of question if you are very clear about the XSLT version you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a different method to achieve the same result, which you may find more convenient to adapt to your situation:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="pi" match="processing-instruction()" use="generate-id(following-sibling::*[1])" />

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <root>
        <xsl:for-each select="data">
            <data>
                <xsl:for-each select="comment">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="key('pi', generate-id())" />
                    <xsl:copy-of select="." />
                </xsl:for-each>
            </data>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </root>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: yes!  this looks super clean and, based on early smoke testing, looks great.  before digging into how xsl keys work, I'm assuming this is something along the lines of "assign a key to every processing instruction (due to the `match` attribute) with the value of calling the `generate-id` function on `following-sibling::*[1]`. If so, this seems like its saying take the first instance, i.e. [1], of all of the sibling nodes.  If that is the case, then how do they get associated to the element in scope, i.e. what is being iterated over in for-each?

Comment: The way this works is that every processing instruction gets indexed with the id of the first following-sibling element. This allows each element to select "its own" processing instructions by calling a key with the value of its id. This is a direct lookup, not an iteration.

Comment: but if there were multiple processing instructions, would processing instruction get the id of processing instruction 2 (i.e. it's first following-sibling element)?  Shouldn't it need to get the id of the first non-processing-instruction following-sibling element?

Comment: A processing instruction is not an element (and vice-versa): https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-datamodel/#Node

Comment: one more thing I noticed is that there could be times wherein I need to pass a reference to `generate-id`.  In my case, I know the element being targetted, so if needed I can just say `generate-id(<expression-targetting-element>)` which works great

Comment: see my latest update.  I think I need to adjust the "index" that my key is using to be based on the processing instructions target node (the data section of the processing instruction).  should be straight forward?

Comment: along these lines, the processing instruction that was indexed by the key would be in the context of its parent element, with the ability to also target a (non-existent) element.  i.e. data/<?format-string comment?> would target data/comment (and be available for injecting while for-eaching over data/comment.  however data/<?xml-multiple color?> would target data/color but data/color might not necessarily be there.  however, I would still want to inject that processing instruction in the result  to reflect an "empty list" (ultimately used downstream for data format conversions)

Comment: You can select the "remaining" PI's using `key('pi', '')`. --- The fact that the PI's contain the name of the element they "belong" to seems irrelevant because the name is not unique. Unless there can be another element with a different name between the PI and its "true" element.

Comment: On second thought, you could use that fact to produce the main bulk of your result using simply: `<xsl:copy-of select="processing-instruction()[.='comment'] | comment" />`. But then selecting the "orphaned" PI/s would not be as trivial - perhaps something like: `<xsl:copy-of select="processing-instruction()[not(.=../*/name())]"/>`.

Comment: what does key('pi', '') do?  I'm wondering how it knows to only get the processing instructions inside the for-each context vs all of them

Comment: I tried the `processing-instruction()[.='comment']` approach, but I need to be inside the for-each (based on the way the xsl was originally generated), so this doesn't really work the same.  If I put it outside the for-each, it doesn't quite associate with each node in the for-each (see how the first comment has two pis, but the second has none...because I did it before the for-each.  see here http://xsltransform.net/gVhDDzC

Comment: in other words,
```xml
          <xsl:for-each select="comment">
            <!-- what would I do here?-->
            <xsl:copy-of select="processing-instruction()[.='comment']" />
            <xsl:copy-of select="." />
          </xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: the only thing about the key approach is that I don't really understand how the key('pi', '') works.  Otherwise, for context, what I was originally trying to do was a mixture of "inside the for-each, look for `preceding-sibling` back until you hit the next node, then capture those until you hit the current node".  So, "give me all the processing instructions between the current node and the previous node"

Comment: I am afraid this is getting out of hand. We are discussing different possible methods all at once. I suggest you pick one method and then, if necessary, post a new question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251763/discussion-between-sparty02-and-michael-hor257k).

Comment: resummarized in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75401863/mapping-processing-instructions-in-the-current-scope-in-xsl

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I fully follow your description. Perhaps something like this can work for you:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <root>
        <xsl:for-each select="data">
            <data>
                <xsl:for-each-group select="* | processing-instruction()" group-ending-with="*">
                    <xsl:if test="current-group()[last()][self::comment]">
                        <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()" />
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each-group>
                <xsl:copy-of select="text" />
            </data>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </root>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This does seem to work!  So, if I wanted to do this somewhat generically, it looks like I could use the same style of `for-each-group` for each node I'm selecting.  In other words, like this (replacing the `copy-of` for the `text` element with a similar `for-each-group` but with a different self::tag-name).  

On a somewhat related note, not that its critical, but could I move the `if` condition for the node name up into the `for-each-group` select?

Comment: Also, is there a version of this where the `for-each-group` copies the processing-instructions that precede the element but _not_ the element itself?

Comment: You can change the last condition `[self::comment]` to include more elements. To exclude the element itself from being copied, you could do `<xsl:copy-of select="current-group()[not(self::*)]"/>`.

Comment: The challenge I'm having (see the update in my question) is that this is in the context of updating existing xsl and I'd like to try and avoid re-arranging it too much.

Comment: I am afraid I don't see your existing XSLT so I don't know what "re-arranging it too much" means. You could use `xsl:apply-templates` instead of `xsl:copy-of` and add a template for each element. Or perhaps use the other method I have just now posted.