# Mapping processing instructions in the current scope in XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

We have a process in which a graphical tool has been used to define mapping transforms from xml->xml. This tool spits out very verbose (not necessarily elegant) xsl transforms that make heavy use of `for-each` and `copy-of`, changing fields as needed within the `for-each` scope of each element. Here is an example:

An XSL might look something like:

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="/root">
    <root>
      <xsl:for-each select="data">
        <data>
          <xsl:copy-of select="id" />
          <xsl:copy-of select="comment" />
          <detail>
            <xsl:for-each select="detail">
              <xsl:copy-of select="name" />
              <preference>
                <xsl:value-of select="favorite" />
              </preference>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </detail>
        </data>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </root>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This transform is:

- dropping the `text` element inside `/root/data`
- changing the name of the `favorite` element to `preference`

Given this transform (reference in http://xsltransform.net/a9GPgr/1), the following source xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <data>
    <id>123</id>
    <comment>hello</comment>
    <comment>goodbye</comment>
    <text>bar</text>
    <detail>
      <name>bob</name>
      <favorite>cake</favorite>
    </detail>
  </data>
</root>
```

will result in this target xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <data>
    <id>123</id>
    <comment>hello</comment>
    <comment>goodbye</comment>
    <detail>
      <name>bob</name>
      <preference>cake</preference>
    </detail>
  </data>
</root>
```

Now, the source xml has evolved to include processing instructions (that are used downstream to decide how to further transform the xml downstream).  The source xml now looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <data>
    <?format-number id?>
    <id>123</id>
    <?xml-multiple comment?>
    <?format-string comment?>
    <comment>hello</comment>
    <?format-string comment?>
    <comment>goodbye</comment>
    <?format-string text?>
    <text>bar</text>
    <detail>
      <?format-string name?>
      <name>bob</name>
      <?format-string favorite?>
      <favorite>cake</favorite>
    </detail>
    <?xml-multiple colors?>
  </data>
</root>
```

Some insight:

- the processing instruction has a name and a "target" aspect to it.  the "target" defines what element the processing instruction "belongs to"
- the `format-number` processing instruction hints that downstream should treat this as a number (not a string)
- the `format-string` processing instruction hints that downstream should treat this as a number
- the `xml-multiple` processing instruction hints that downstream should treat the target sibling elements as an array
- the `xml-multiple` processing instruction may not have an instance of its target element in the source, i.e. `<?xml-multiple colors?>` above doesn't "annotate" a `<colors>` element, which hints that downstream should create an empty array

Now, the challenge is that these processing instructions aren't carried through when running the xml transform above.  Instead of doing mapping changes in the tool, I have a program that changes the original xsl and can add new content to it in well-known locations (i.e. when it sees that its using `for-each` and friends).

In this respect, I need to figure out what the "new" xsl should look like in order to maintain thsese processing instructions.  My mental model for what needs to get changed is:

1. when copying over content, ensure that you also copy over all processing instructions between the "previous" element and the "current element".  For the following snippet, the `<id>` element is annotated with the `<?format-number id?>` processing instruction, the first `<comment>` element is annotated with two processing instructions (`<?xml-multiple comment?>` and `<?format-string comment?>`).

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <data>
    <?format-number id?>
    <id>123</id>
    <?xml-multiple comment?>
    <?format-string comment?>
    <comment>hello</comment>
    <?format-string comment?>
    <comment>goodbye</comment>
  </data>
</root>
```

2. ensure that processing instructions that don't have an associated target element are also copied over.  For the following snippet, the `<id>` element is annotated with the `<?format-number id?>` processing instruction and there is an orphaned processing instruction at the end that doesn't annotate anything (`<?xml-multiple colors?>`).

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <data>
    <?format-number id?>
    <id>123</id>
    <?xml-multiple colors?>
  </data>
</root>
```

Also note that the orphaned `xml-multiple` doesn't have to be at the end, it could be between elements, as in:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <data>
    <?format-number id?>
    <id>123</id>
    <?xml-multiple colors?>
    <?format-string text?>
    <text>bar</text>
  </data>
</root>
```

An XSL might look something like the following (notice that I can "inject" some xsl at each logical place where an element is being processed in scope):

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="/root">
    <root>
      <xsl:for-each select="data">
        <data>
          <!-- what would I do here? some usage of preceding-sibling and processing instruction maybe? -->
          <xsl:copy-of select="???" />
          <xsl:copy-of select="id" />
          <!-- same -->
          <xsl:copy-of select="???" />
          <xsl:copy-of select="comment" />
          <detail>
            <!-- same -->
            <xsl:copy-of select="???" />
            <xsl:for-each select="detail">
              <!-- same -->
              <xsl:copy-of select="???" />
              <xsl:copy-of select="name" />
              <!-- same -->
              <xsl:copy-of select="???" />
              <preference>
                <xsl:value-of select="favorite" />
              </preference>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </detail>
        </data>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </root>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Based on the transform, the result should be:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <data>
    <?format-number id?>
    <id>123</id>
    <?xml-multiple comment?>
    <?format-string comment?>
    <comment>hello</comment>
    <?format-string comment?>
    <comment>goodbye</comment>
    <detail>
      <?format-string name?>
      <name>bob</name>
      <?format-string preference?>
      <preference>cake</preference>
    </detail>
    <?xml-multiple colors?>
  </data>
</root>
```

Comment: What if you will start using a so called "Identity Transform" pattern instead?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of using of the *Identity Transform* pattern.

The idea of it is very simple. You deal with nodes that need to be removed or modified. Everything else is copied to the output by itself without explicit referencing nodes one by one.

**Input XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <data>
        <?format-number id?>
        <id>123</id>
        <?xml-multiple comment?>
        <?format-string comment?>
        <comment>hello</comment>
        <?format-string comment?>
        <comment>goodbye</comment>
        <?format-string text?>
        <text>bar</text>
        <detail>
            <?format-string name?>
            <name>bob</name>
            <?format-string favorite?>
            <favorite>cake</favorite>
        </detail>
        <?xml-multiple colors?>
    </data>
</root>
```

**XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!--remove text element-->
    <xsl:template match="text"/>

    <!--remove text element processing-instruction-->
    <xsl:template match="processing-instruction('format-string')
                    [contains(., 'text')]"/>

    <!--change favorite element to preference-->
    <xsl:template match="favorite">
        <preference>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </preference>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?>
<root>
  <data>
    <?format-number id?>
    <id>123</id>
    <?xml-multiple comment?>
    <?format-string comment?>
    <comment>hello</comment>
    <?format-string comment?>
    <comment>goodbye</comment>
    <detail>
      <?format-string name?>
      <name>bob</name>
      <?format-string favorite?>
      <preference>cake</preference>
    </detail>
    <?xml-multiple colors?>
  </data>
</root>
```

Comment: If I wrote it by hand, this is how I'd do the XSL as well.  But this is why I mentioned that it was generated by a tool (that supports graphical changes).  In that respect, it would be too much work/risk to rewrite these XSL.  In this respect, the only practical solution is to transform the generated XSL in a predictable way that includes instructions that maintain the processing instructions.  i.e.  gui -> xsl -> enrich with pi support -> xsl that can be used

Comment: Maybe you can speak with the vendor of the tool, and request some enhancements

Comment: that's an avenue, but it doesn't address the question at hand

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a different approach. Start with a hand-written XSLT stylesheet that converts the XML to a more conventional form. Then use the mapping tool to generate a transformation on this XML; then post-process the result of that mapping tool with another XSLT stylesheet that reinstates the processing instructions.

Trying to automate the conversion of generated XSLT code so it does a different transformation from the one it was designed to do seems -- let's say -- challenging.

(Personally, my experience of using mapping tools to generate XSLT is very negative; it's more trouble than it's worth, and you'd be better off writing the XSLT code by hand. But your mileage may vary...)